# Regex for selecting elements from transform matrix

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, css

I have a string of style transform given in the following way :

`matrix(0.312321, -0.949977, 0.949977, 0.312321, 0, 0)`

How can I form an array containing elements of this matrix ? Any tips how to write regex for this ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it like this...

```
// original string follows exactly this pattern (no spaces at front or back for example)
var string = "matrix(0.312321, -0.949977, 0.949977, 0.312321, 0, 0)";

// firstly replace one or more (+) word characters (\w) followed by `(` at the start (^) with a `[`
// then replace the `)` at the end with `]`
var modified = string.replace(/^\w+\(/,"[").replace(/\)$/,"]");
// this will leave you with a string: "[0.312321, -0.949977, 0.949977, 0.312321, 0, 0]"

// then parse the new string (in the JSON encoded form of an array) as JSON into a variable
var array = JSON.parse(modified)

// check it is correct
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Thx, but this was good enough for me: `JSON.parse(\`[${string.slice(7,-1)}]\`)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way.  Parse out the numbers part with regex and then use the `split()` method:

```
var s = "matrix(0.312321, -0.949977, 0.949977, 0.312321, 0, 0)";
s.match(/[0-9., -]+/)[0].split(", "); // results in ["0.312321", "-0.949977", "0.949977", "0.312321", "0", "0"]
```

Comment: don't work with `e-` example:  `matrix(6.12323e-17, -0.949977, 0.949977, 0.312321, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^matrix\(([+\-\d.]+), ([+\-\d.]+), ([+\-\d.]+), ([+\-\d.]+), ([+\-\d.]+), ([+\-\d.]+)\)$/
    .exec(str).slice(1);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AtasB/)

Comment: don't work for `e-` `matrix(6.12323e-17, 1, -1, 6.12323e-17, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like that:

```
var string = "matrix(0.312321, -0.949977, 0.949977, 0.312321, 0, 0)";

var array = string.replace(/^.*\((.*)\)$/g, "$1").split(/, +/);
```

Notice that in this way the array will contains string. If you want real number an easy way is:

```
array = array.map(Number);
```

Your js engine needs to support [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or have a shim for it (of course you can also convert them manually).